# SharePoint 2013 Online - Missing Follow Link

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

The Follow link is missing from out SharePoint 2013 Online team site. Share and Edit links are displayed.

In Site Settings > Site Features, Following Content is Active (having this active should have enabled the Follow link).

We have not customized template files or added CSS to hide anything.

How do I display the Follow link?

Comment: Don't have a SP Online to test, but for what I know, without any template (including masterpage)/CSS customization or deactivation of the Following Content -feature, it's next to impossible to hide the Follow-link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have activated the feature, you need to setup onedrive by clicking on it from the app launcher. Once that is setup, the follow icon would start appearing on the site as well as documents. This[one drive setup] needs to be done by each user on the tenant.

[image]

Comment: If you don't see OneDrive, it could be you have an Exchange Online Plan 1 license. While SharePoint is functional, certain features are unavailable. This also impacts the SharePoint and OneDrive mobile apps.